# Bolding certain characters in a CCombobox entry (C++, MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc, ccombobox

I have a CComboBox containing strings of serial numbers. I want to be able to bold individual characters in the string. Like for instance, I would like to be able to make the second string `87650123` show up as **87**65**01**23.

[image]

I have seen some posts about bolding a whole individual string entry in a CCombobox, but not individual characters. Would this be possible? Thanks in advance.

I have attempted bolding the entire entry to start, which was successful, but have not been able to do individual characters.

Comment: You'll have to owner draw the `CCombobox` and draw the strings yourself as you
want them to look. It's not that hard but not that easy either. `NM_CUSTOMDRAW`  is sent for each item. You should be responding to that. [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/646482/Custom-Controls-in-Win-API-Control-Customization)

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev I'll give that a try; thank you :)